# django-oscar 3.0 with paypal payment

Tags: django, paypal, checkout, django-oscar

I am fairly new with Django as well as Djnago-oscar, so far I have django-oscar store setup and I am trying to integrate with paypal but because I am running django.oscar 3.x 'django-oscar-paypal' doesn't work for me and there is not enough documentation on how to implement payments.

My checkout process:

1. Adding items to cart
2. User enter details including shipping etc
3. Select payment method, review redirect to Paypal to complement payment
4. Redirect back to website and confirm the order

On `paymentMethodeView` I have created a form to get the payment method, and on `paymentDetailsView` I have `handle_payment`

```
def handle_payment(self, order_number, order_total, **kwargs):
        method = self.checkout_session.payment_method()
        if method == 'pt': #payment terms admin manually invoice
            return self.handle_pt_payment(order_number, order_total, **kwargs)
        elif method == 'paypal_payment':
            return self.handle_paypal_payment(order_number, order_total, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise PaymentError(_('Bad payment method in handle_payment!'))
```

And at `handle_paypal_payment` function I am not sure how to proceed.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I'm currently looking to implement a few different payment gateways and was curious: is this method of obtaining the payment method best practice? Also, would you mind sharing the `paymentMethodeView`?

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting away from your website is an old way to process payments. Don't do it; there should be no redirecting away.

Instead, make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls); there is a Checkout-Python-SDK you can use. These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The capture one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow, which involves no redirects: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

If, in the success section of that code you want to redirect somewhere else on your site after a transaction is processed (like a thank you and confirmation page), do so with JavaScript.